# Reading Textfile

Tags: python, text, text-files

I have this code that writes random numbers to text file:

```
import random
members = 5
participants=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
random.shuffle(participants)
with open("myfile1.txt",'w') as tf:
    for i in range(len(participants) // members + 1):
         group = participants[i*members:i*members + members]
         for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant))
            tf.write("\n")
```

I was trying to use this to sum the random numbers it gives me

```
import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt("myfile1.txt")
def MA1001():
    return(data[0:,0].sum())
```

However, it gives me "too many indices for array" error?
Is there any way to get around this or is there a better method?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is it is not making a 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('myfile1.txt','r') as file:
    print (sum(map(int,file.read().splitlines())))
```

You could try this without numpy

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I know the problem, will fix

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it

Comment: perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000, you could simply do `print sum(map(int,file.read().splitlines()))`

Comment: Then you'd have to close it :(

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what you want to achieve, nevertheless: you write one number per row in the file and loadtext will return an array (shape (20,)). Hence, data.sum() is enough. There is no second dimension.

Comment: So the code writes out 20 numbers randomly onto a text file, i was wondering if there was a way to find the sum of all of these

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `numpy` you can simply do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("myfile1.txt")
def MA1001(data):
    print(data.sum())

MA1001(data)
```

Comment: Pretty much what the other answer said

Comment: yeah, I didn't read it to be honest - just saw OP's comment and thought hadn't been answered... up-voted though :)